# AppCenter don't open

Tags: appcenter

My AppCenter don't open. I've tried to reinstall but don't work. The app show that there's new updates, but, it don't open. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal type this command and see what error or output it gives..share the result also

```
io.elementary.appcenter
```